# Resume stalled Apple Watch app update

Tags: apple-watch

Several of the apps on my Apple Watch were updated by their vendors, but for some reason the apps have been stuck in update mode for about a week now. Is there a way to resume the update? Restarting both the Apple Watch and the paired iPhone doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried unpairing and re-pairing the iPhone and the Apple Watch? (Posted as a comment, not an answer, because I have no Apple Watch experience on which to base this suggestion.)

Comment: @user24601 I think that is a good suggestion, but I wanted to avoid it because I wanted to avoid having to redo any other settings.

Comment: Doesn't it take a backup?

Comment: @user24601 I don't think there is a backup feature, I haven't found one. It's fairly simple so a backup isn't as critical as with a regular iOS device.

Comment: [You sure about that?](http://www.imore.com/how-restore-your-apple-watch-backup) :)

Comment: @user24601 Interesting. Thanks for the link. "A backup of your Apple Watch is only created when you unpair a Watch. That means if you've never unpaired your Apple Watch or restored it, you may not have a backup to restore from."

Comment: "You'll have to have unpair your old Watch at some point in order for a backup to have happened." I think that means that when you initiate the unpairing, it'll take a backup right there.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that even though the transitional icons are showing up on the Apple Watch, on the Apple Watch app the "Show App on Apple Watch" option was turned off for those apps. Turning on the option restarts the download. In any case this appears to be a bug.

Although this works, it can be slow to attempt to figure out which apps aren't downloaded and turning on the option, perhaps someone could suggest a more efficient method. Also, @user24601's suggestion might be something to try.